# UITextView cursor and emoji problems

Tags: swift, cursor, uitextview, emoji

something weird is happening when I insert an emoji in my textview, some extra space is added. And also my cursor height is acting strange. Sometimes is very large. I tried to fix the cursor problem, everything is working fine until I insert an emoji(again), the cursor goes little bit up.

```
 override func caretRect(for position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect
{
    var superRect = super.caretRect(for: position)
    guard let isFont = self.font else { return superRect}
    superRect.size.height = isFont.pointSize - isFont.descender

    return superRect
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does it work properly if you don't override `caretRect`?

Comment: Hmm.. I had to use caretRect, and now 5 mins ago, I realized that if I remove this line 'mutableParagraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = 10' it's ok...

Comment: I still don't know why is this extra space after every emoji...